# R Studio error - "Unexpected input"

Tags: r, rstudio

The following simple example works fine if I save call it from the RGui Console.  However, if I run it in RStudio I get an error that reads:

> "Error: unexpected input in "best <- function(state, outcome) {

*I had to force Quit RStudio so I am wondering if that could be causing it?*

```
 best <- function(state, outcome) {

      data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", header = TRUE)

      if (is.element(state,data[,"State"]) != TRUE)
        stop("invalid state")

      head(data)

    }


    best('TX','heart attack')
```

Comment: try running `getwd()` in the RGui and RStudio.  I would guess that they are different.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin.  I should have mentioned that I made sure they were the same.

Comment: @Benjamin I'm not sure how that would explain the error given at all

Comment: @Dason, based only on the code snippet, it seemed like the only thing that would result in an error simply by switching from RGui to RStudio.  My next question would be if running a fresh session in each application produces the same results.  Perhaps there's something floating in the environment somewhere.

Comment: Well, I uninstalled/reinstalled R-Studio and it still doesn't work there. I can still run other R scripts that I wrote with no issues.  Just wondering if anyone had ever experienced this.

Comment: I'm afraid this is new to me and I'm unable to replicate the error.

Comment: @Benjamin but the error message itself really has nothing to do with the body of the function.  It seems more like an issue with the way it's being sourced/run in RStudio.  plotthewise - do you get an error if you try to do the same thing but with a simpler function?

Comment: Ok, I restarted my computer and now it works.  Thanks for helping me look into this.  I think it must have been the forced quit somehow but I don't understand enough to know for sure.

Comment: I should also mention that I copied it to a new Script and saved it as well. So maybe that's what fixed it.  I have not idea but thanks again.

Comment: I'm guessing you copy + pasted this code from a PDF? There's a bug in RStudio where invalid characters can get inserted when pasting stuff copied from a PDF that cause these kinds of issues.

Comment: Kevin, I didn't copy all of it but I did copy the csv file name from a PDF.  I am betting that you are correct.